# Get XML-node by attribute name

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML-structure:

```
   <Folder>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <Data name="Id">
            <value>152285415</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="Name">
            <value>Tester</value>
          </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
```

and I need to directly access the  of the -Object with the attribute "name" = "Id".

So I tried this:

```
$xml->Document->Folder->Placemark->ExtendedData->xpath('data[@name="Id"]')
```

but that gives and empty array.

What I need in the end is "152285415"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you missed a key word in your question. What output do you want to get?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger you should close this question by accepting an answer.

Comment: @ishegg you're right, just done! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to access what you want directly:

```
<?php
$xml = '<Folder>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <Data name="Id">
            <value>152285415</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="Name">
            <value>Tester</value>
          </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result = $xml->xpath('/Folder/Placemark/ExtendedData/Data[@name="Id"]');
echo "Value: ".$result[0]->value; // Value: 152285415
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gELIg)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the job:

```
<?php

$xml = '<Folder>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <Data name="Id">
            <value>152285415</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="Name">
            <value>Tester</value>
          </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml->Placemark->ExtendedData->Data as $item) {

    if($item->attributes()['name'] == 'Id') {
        echo $item->value;
    }

}
```

Comment: sure, it does. However directly accessing that object without looping would be much nicer, don't you think?

Comment: It would. Hopefully somebody more talented than me comes up with a better answer and then I can learn from them!

Answer (score 0):

To not worry about the overall hierarchy of the document (although this is abused quite a bit) is to use // as the first part of the XPath.  So the query can be written as in...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xmlDoc = <<<XML
<Folder>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="Id">
        <value>152285415</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Name">
        <value>Tester</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlDoc);
$value = $xml->xpath('//Data[@name="Id"]/value')[0];
echo "Value=".$value.PHP_EOL;
```

Although note that $value is still a SimpleXMLElement Object, so if you need it as a string, you should use `(string)$value`.  In the example, `echo` will automatically do the conversion for you.